# Erlang, creating mnesia table index

Tags: erlang, mnesia

Why the first element of a record can't be used as table index?

This is not working:

```
(hlu@192.168.0.40)16> rd(pilot, {id, name, weight, phone}).
pilot
(hlu@192.168.0.40)17> mnesia:create_table(pilot,
(hlu@192.168.0.40)17> [{attributes, record_info(fields, pilot)},
(hlu@192.168.0.40)17> {index, [#pilot.id]},
(hlu@192.168.0.40)17> {disc_copies, Nodes},
(hlu@192.168.0.40)17> {type, set}]).
{aborted,{bad_type,pilot,{index,[{2,ordered}]}}}
```

This is working:

```
(hlu@192.168.0.40)18> rf(pilot).                                
ok
(hlu@192.168.0.40)19> rd(pilot, {name, weight, phone, id}).     
pilot
(hlu@192.168.0.40)20> mnesia:create_table(pilot,
(hlu@192.168.0.40)20> [{attributes, record_info(fields, pilot)},
(hlu@192.168.0.40)20> {index, [#pilot.id]},
(hlu@192.168.0.40)20> {disc_copies, Nodes},
(hlu@192.168.0.40)20> {type, set}]).
{atomic,ok}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a single statement in the documentation:

> The first record attribute is the primary key, or key for short.

Later on:

> index. This is a list of attribute names, or integers, which specify the tuple positions on which Mnesia is to build and maintain an extra index table.

Answer (score 1):

> Why the first element of a record can't be used as table index?

By default, it's already an index: the first element of a record is the ***primary key.***